# Error from NUnit3 beta

Tags: c#, jenkins, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm working with NUnit 3.0 beta to making test on Jenkins. It's working well on my local project, but when I put it on Jenkins system, I got XML result like below

```
<test-results name="" total="0" errors="0" failures="0" not-run="0" inconclusive="0" ignored="0" skipped="0" invalid="0" date="2016-03-02" time="15:54:20">
<environment nunit-version="1.0.0.0" clr-version="4.0" os-version="Microsoft Windows NT" platform="Win32NT" cwd="M:\Works" machine-name="test" user="admin" user-domain="test"/>
<culture-info current-culture="en-US" current-uiculture="en-US"/>
<test-suite type="Assembly" name="EndpointBaseFramework.dll" executed="False" result="Success">
<properties>
<property name="_SKIPREASON" value="Constructor on type 'NUnit.Framework.Api.FrameworkController' not found."/>
</properties>
<reason>
<message>
<![CDATA[
Constructor on type 'NUnit.Framework.Api.FrameworkController' not found.
]]>
</message>
</reason>
<results/>
</test-suite>
</test-results>
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

NUnit 3 has been released for around 6 months. Are you sure you are using one of the betas and not 3.0.1?

The NUnit plugin for Jenkins was last updated in [June 2015](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin), well before the release of NUnit 3 and the source hasn't been updated in [10 months](https://github.com/jenkinsci/nunit-plugin). NUnit 3 is a rewrite and you cannot run it using older NUnit 2 runners.

Until the plugin is update to support NUnit 3, you will need to run your tests using the NUnit3 Console Runner. I would add the [NUnit.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Console/) NuGet package to your solution. This will pull nunit3-console.exe into your packages directory. From there, create a post build step in Jenkins to execute nunit3-console.exe on your test assemblies. See the [NUnit Documentation for command line options.](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line)